# code in the kernel space for swapping the contents of two non-overlapping 4KB arrays

Tags: operating-system

The below code in the kernel space is for swapping the contents of two non-overlapping **4KB** arrays, does it have any bugs:

```
1: void swap4kb(void* a, void* b) {
2:   char tmp[4096];
3:   assert(a != NULL);
4:   assert(b != NULL);
5:   memcpy(tmp, a, 4096);
6:   memcpy(a, b, 4096);
7:   memcpy(b, tmp, 4096);
8: }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it have any bugs?

It doesn't have bugs; assuming that it doesn't need to be done "atomically", and assuming that you have enough space on the stack for the `char tmp[4096];` array.

However, a lot of kernels use a "one kernel stack per task" model, which means there's an incentive to use small kernel stacks. For example, if there's 100 processes that have an average of 10 threads each; then 1 MiB kernel stacks would add up to almost 1 GiB of RAM consumed by kernel stacks alone. Using 4 KiB kernel stacks makes some sense (due to 4 KiB being the size of a page in most systems), and in that case your code will overflow the stack and can be considered buggy for that reason.

In any case; the mistake is assuming this code makes sense in the first place. Typically you'd have "pointers to arrays" and swap the pointers instead, which avoids the overhead of copying the data itself.

Comment: Thanks you. So how could I modify it to use "pointers to arrays"?

Comment: @user836026: That'd be like "`swap_pointers(void **a, void **b) { void * temp = *a; *a = *b; *b = temp; }`"; but you'll need to change all the code that uses the arrays so that they use (modifiable) pointers and not fixed locations, starting with defining them as pointers (e.g. maybe `uint8_t data1[4096]; void *a = data1;` and not `uint8_t a[4096];`).